# How to only initialise some of the properties in a Swift class

Tags: swift, initialization

It's known that Swift compiler forces all the properties to be initialised in a constructer. However, sometimes I only want to have some of the properties to be initialised. Below is an example, I only have to use variable b in the second constructer and no need for the variable a but the complier is complaining "a is not initialised". I wonder how to deal with this case.

```
class aClass{
 var a:String
 var b:String

 init(a:String){
    self.a = "a"
 }

 init(a:String, b:String){
    self.a = "a"
    self.b = "b"
 }
```

}

Comment: If your design calls for an instance variable that you sometimes don't care about, you should probably look closely at it and see if there's a better way of designing the class. (You may find that, for example, what you need is two classes, with one derived from the other, where the derived class adds both your `b` property and the constructor that takes the `b` parameter.) But if you do really need a variable that will sometimes be uninitialised, i.e. nil, you should just make it an Optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what optionals are for. your declaration of property b can change to `var b: String?`. This will make it so you don't have to give it a value in init. Then, when you want to use it, `if let self.b = "my string" {...}` or, if you know it has a value, you can force unwrap it: `var myOtherString = b!`.

Comment: That answers my question:) Swift is so awesome and so do you. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to click the checkmark :)